# change ID number to smooth out duplicates in a table

Tags: sql-server-2000, duplicate-data

I have run into this problem that I'm trying to solve: Every day I import new records into a table that have an ID number.

Most of them are new (have never been seen in the system before) but some are coming in again. What I need to do is to append an alpha to the end of the ID number if the number is found in the archive, but only if the data in the row is different from the data in the archive, and this needs to be done sequentially, IE, if 12345 is seen a 2nd time with different data, I change it to 12345A, and if 12345 is seen again, and is again different, I need to change it to 12345B, etc.

Originally I tried using a `where` loop where it would put all the 'seen again' records in a temp table, and then assign A first time, then delete those, assign B to what's left, delete those, etc., till the temp table was empty, but that hasn't worked out.

Alternately, I've been thinking of trying subqueries as in:

```
update table
set IDNO= (select max idno from archive) plus 1
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

How about this as an idea? Mind you, this is basically pseudocode so adjust as you see fit.

With "src" as the table that all the data will ultimately be inserted into, and "TMP" as your temporary table.. and this is presuming that the ID column in TMP is a *double*.

```
do
    update tmp set id = id + 0.01 where id in (select id from src);
until no_rows_changed;

alter table TMP change id into id varchar(255);

update TMP set id = concat(int(id), chr((id - int(id)) * 100 + 64);

insert into SRC select * from tmp;
```

Comment: Ok that would help with the part about getting the letters in the first place... how would you go about figuring out what the previous largest ID was and continuing off of it? i.e. 123, 123A, and 123B are already in the archive, and 123 comes in again, so it should be changed to 123C...how would I get 123B as the largest in the 123 series?

Comment: HM! ok, now I got what your saying... that should be rather easy as your just using grouping functions now. Here, with a little tweaking it should work. This'll give you how many is in each ID sequence and what is the largest ID. MYSQL: "Select convert(id, signed), count(*), max(id) from SRC group by convert(id, signed)" As for converting it to Sql 2000, the dialect shouldn't be that much different.

Comment: well I know that sql server doesn't have a 'signed' data type, so what exactly is a "signed"? and how does it get rid of the alpha for the purpose of grouping and comparing?

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you get to 12345Z?

Anyway, change the table structure slightly, here's the recipe:

1. Drop any indices on `ID`.
2. Split `ID` (apparently varchar) into `ID_Num` (long int) and `ID_Alpha` (varchar, not null).  Make the default value for `ID_Alpha` an empty string (`''`).
   So, *12345B* (varchar) becomes *12345* (long int) and *'B'* (varchar), etc.
3. Create a unique, ideally clustered, index on columns `ID_Num` and `ID_Alpha`.
   Make this the primary key. Or, if you must, use an auto-incrementing integer as a pseudo primary key.
4. Now, when adding new data, finding duplicate ID number's is trivial and the last ID_Alpha can be obtained with a simple `max()` operation.
5. Resolving duplicate ID's should now be an easier task, using either a while loop or a cursor (if you must).
   But, it should also be possible to avoid the "Row by agonizing row" (RBAR), and use a set-based approach.  A few days of reading [Jeff Moden articles](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Authors/Articles/Jeff_Moden/80567/), should give you ideas in that regard.

Comment: a couple of caveats that I'm wondering how your explained approach might deal with: these ID numbers pertain to a specific customer, which is the reason for the alpha character (it leaves a string from which one can easily tell what the original was), so I cannot change the integer itself at all, so how does that fit with the clustered index? also the ID number can only change when the rest of the row changes: if we get a row with the same info as a previous row, it needs to have the same ID number (which includes the alpha); one other point of information: these rows do have a unique id also

Comment: You won't be changing the integer (customer ID), just modeling the data more correctly to make processing vastly easier -- hence split the base out from the suffix into 2 columns. ... Clustered indices seems like a topic to delve into later (or Google), you've got bigger fish to fry.  For now, trust me that this will help performance. ... I understand the question as posted, and gave an outline of how to approach it. Note that we are not going to write such involved code from scratch for you. You must break the problem into chunks, and [show some effort in the question](http://goo.gl/NiAzX).

Answer (score 0):

Here is my final solution:

```
update a
set IDnum=b.IDnum
from tempimiportable A inner join 
    (select * from archivetable
     where IDnum in 
     (select max(IDnum) from archivetable
      where IDnum in 
       (select IDnum from tempimporttable)
      group by left(IDnum,7) 
      )
     ) b
on b.IDnum like a.IDnum + '%'
WHERE 
*row from tempimport table = row from archive table*
```

to set incoming rows to the same IDnum as old rows, and then

```
update a
set patient_account_number = case 
    when len((select max(IDnum) from archive where left(IDnum,7) = left(a.IDnum,7)))= 7 then a.IDnum + 'A'
    else left(a.IDnum,7) + char(ascii(right((select max(IDnum) from archive where left(IDnum,7) = left(a.IDnum,7)),1))+1)
    end
from tempimporttable a
where not exists ( *select rows from archive table* )
```

I don't know if anyone wants to delve too far into this, but I appreciate contructive criticism...